# Spring MVC 3: Interceptor return view on false

Tags: java, spring-mvc, interceptor

I'm using an interceptor to restrict access to certain users in the app. For instance:

```java
@Override
public boolean preHandle(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Object handler) throws Exception
{
    Logger.logRequest(request);
    return list.contains(user);
}
```

If the list contains the user, it completes the request. Otherwise, it does nothing.

How do I display a custom page if the user doesn't have access? Right now, if it's false, it just shows a blank page which is not great for user experience.

Comment: You can use a RequestDispatcher from the request to forward to some jsp. Or you can send a redirect.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It looks like you can do a response redirect without hitting the servlet. The following works:

```
    if (list.contains(user))
        return true;
    else
    {
        //set up the view
        response.sendRedirect("nope_view");
        return false;
    }
```

Comment: Careful with the naming. The String you pass to the redirect isn't a view name, but actually makes a new request.

Comment: Thanks for the reminder. I'll have to redirect to another servlet or static view.